# File System.Web.Services was not found

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-assembly

I'm running an service on an server which calls an assembly to retrieve data from an webservice. The called assembly tries to establish an connection to an webservice. When trying to connect to the Web Service specified in the configuration file I always get the following message in the log File of the assembly:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: fatal Error: File file:\C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a was not found !
```

I looked inside the folder the error message stated and found the System.Web.Services.dll.
Unit testing the assembly on my local machine runs without any errors.

I already used google to find an solution for  this problem but couldn't find anything. Any suggestions or solutions? Im really stuck in this problem at the moment.

Comment: The mentioned assembly dll is missing in the server.

Comment: ..that's what I also thought but the mentioned assembly dll System.Web.Services is availablein C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a and also in C:\Windows\assembly

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding the dll with a reference

Comment: What is your service identity? Does it have right access to the mentioned folder?